# CORS question on using a REACT app with Serverless Framework

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I've seen many posts on this topic, but all of them deal with the CORS error message about missing headers and such.

I'm facing a different issue (I think..) - I'm getting a valid 200 response that looks like this:

> Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://....amazonaws.com/dev/calculate', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
> body: ReadableStream
> bodyUsed: false
> headers: Headers {}
> ok: true
> redirected: false
> status: 200
> statusText: ""
> type: "cors"
> url: "https://....amazonaws.com/dev/calculate"

The details:

I have a simple React app that uses a AWS Lambda function to calculate a sum of 2 numbers. I used Serverless to deploy this to AWS. The *.yml looks like so:

```
service: reactcalculatorserverless
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

functions:
  doCalculation:
      handler: lambdas/doCalculation.handler
      events:
          - http:
              path: calculate
              method: POST
              cors: true
```

The Lambda:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const { operand1, operand2, operator } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let result = 0;

    switch (operator)
    {
        case "+":
            result = operand1 + operand2;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = operand1 - operand2;
            break;
        case "*":
        case "X":
        case "x":
            result = operand1 * operand2;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = operand1 / operand2;
            break;
    }    
    
    const responseBody = {
        "result" : result
    };

    const response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(responseBody),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };

    return response;
```

Of course this all works well with Postman.

Is this a CORS error, even though it is a valid response header? Since I have "cors=true" in the yml file, it did do the right thing and added the OPTIONS in API Gateway, but still I don't get the correct response from the Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the origins to serverless yml. Also wild card origin is not allowed if Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set True.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#enabling-cors